# When using typescript in redux, questions related to initialization of initialstate

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export interface Book{
    title : String, 
    contents: String,
    thumbnail: String,
    liked: boolean
}

const initialState : Book = {
    Books : Book[],
    likedBook: Book[]
};
```

I have created a variable called books with type Book. But it didn't work. What's the problem? Thanks for explaining why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues there:

1. You've used the name `Books`, not `books`.
2. It's a property, not a variable.
3. You've given the type `Book` to `initialState`, but the properties you're initializing it with don't match the properties the `Book` type defines.
4. `Book[]` is not how you create an empty array in JavaScript/TypeScript. It's just `[]`. The type comes from the type declaration, if any, of the variable/property you're assigning it too.

I think you may have wanted this:

```typescript
export interface Book{
    title : String, 
    contents: String,
    thumbnail: String,
    liked: boolean
}

// An iterface/type to use for `initialState` (you could also define it in line)
interface State {
    books: Book[];
    likedBooks: Book[]; // I've changed this to the plural, since it's an array
}

const initialState : State = {
    books: [],
    likedBooks: [],
};
```

or if you don't want to define the `State` type, you can do it inline in a couple of ways when defining `initialState`:

```typescript
const initialState: {books: Book[]; likedBook: Book[];} = {
    books: [],
    likedBooks: [],
};
// Or
const initialState = {
    books: [] as Book[],
    likedBooks: [] as Book[],
};
```

Comment: Thanks to you, my question has been perfectly solved! Have a happy day 